# How do i do this in c++, print the highest 10 numbers out of this list?

Tags: c++

How do I print the highest 10 numbers out of this list?

This is my list of numbers, I am new to programming, I know I have to use an array but I am not sure after that.

```
     2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71
```

Comment: please dont give me the code, tell me what i need to do.

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: Is your list of numbers always going to be sorted? If so, this is *very* easy.

Comment: Your question is not at all specific. Do you know how to print one number? Do you know how to represent the list? Do you know how to find the highest number? Do you know how to create `main()`? Try *something* and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: no they wont always be sorted

Comment: The highest ten numbers in your list are  31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, and 71. So `cout << "31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71" << std::endl` should do the trick.

Comment: i have this vector then how would i sort it, from highest to lowest vector<int> test;
 test.push_back(3);
 test.push_back(2);
 test.push_back(8);
 test.push_back(23);

Comment: The example given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for `std::sort` should be easy enough to adapt.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to look at the [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) function, in conjunction with the `operator>`.

Comment: Not to mention `operator<<`, and some container type.

Comment: I'd probably use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Answer (score 1):

If you keep these numbers in a vector you can use std::sort()

Comment: vector<int> test;
 test.push_back(3);
 test.push_back(2);
 test.push_back(8);
 test.push_back(23);

Comment: If you keep the numbers in any container which supports random access, you can use `std::sort` (or even better `std::partial_sort`).

Comment: you can initialize vector with an array, you do not need to push_back

Answer (score 0):

Put your numbers in an array
(ideally read the list of numbers in a file)
sort the array in decreasing order (using existing functions, as proposed by other answers, OR, as I guess this is a course exercice, by using the algo explained in class)
for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
print array[i];

Sorry it starts looking like code...

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array first.

Get the size of the aray, and use it as index. Then write a for loop like:

```
for(int index = size -1; index >=0; index--) 
    // print here
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is very big, using `sort` is not very efficient since you only want to find `10` largest element. A better approach is to build a min-heap with `10` elements, when the heap size is smaller than `10`, insert element into the heap. After that, when new elements come, you compare the element with root of heap, if the element is larger than root, insert into heap and remove current heap head, this process repeats until you have finished scanning all elements in list. This algorithm works with time complexity"O(nlogk)", where `n` is the total number of elements and `k` is 10 in this case. more efficient in `O(nlogn)` if you use sorting. You need to understand how binary heap works in C++ and you can apply std containers to implement one that works for you very easily.

However, using `std::sort` is the brute force way and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in couple of ways:
Assuming you have N elements in your list and you have to pick X highest elements. 
1) Sort your array then pick X highest elements elements. Now since sorting will take O(NlogN) time and your selection will take O(X) time overall complexity will be O(NlogN).

2) Dont sort your array, just traverse the list to find the highest element, then traverse again to find the next highest element and so on till you get X highest elements. Complexity O(X*N) which is better the last approach when X < logN.

3) You can optimize the approach 2 by using a fixed(X) sized max heap, Traverse the list  inserting elements into the list if they are greater then the least element in the max heap. Complexity O(NLogX).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
     v.push_back(i);
  }
  std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

  std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4, v.end());
  for(unsigned k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
    std::cout << k << "-th element is " << v[k] << '\n';
  }
}
```

A note on complexity as others already have pointed that out. It is generall *better* to use partial_sort in this case since it has better complexity for this case. But if you just play around with a toy instance then a full sort can solve your problem as well.

Next time, show a little more effort like the code you tried and what you found in literature, etc.